# Validating drop down list that shouldn't accept the default value

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel 5.2 project and I intend to validate a drop down of my categories in a post. All Post should have a category and the default displayed option should not be accepted.

Here's what my select form looks like

```html
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('category_name','Category:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('category_name',$categories,"",['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

    </div>
```

My validation rules

```html
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'=>'required',
            'body'=>'required',
            'category'=>'required|not_in:1'
        ];
    }
}
```

Also heres my table data

```html
<td>{{$post->category['name']}}</td>
```

Yet I am getting this error,the "category field is required".Even though I chose other categories or leave it at default. Kindy help.

Comment: What template engine is this, blade? `looks ugly to me`

Comment: I think you should validate `category_name` and not `category`.

Comment: Yes @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: @Laerte's answer is right. You have different name for form and validation field.

Comment: Ok! I will post it as an answer for further reading.

Comment: Yes, @laerte's is right. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should validate `category_name` and not `category`.

Change the code to:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'=>'required',
            'body'=>'required',
            'category_name'=>'required|not_in:1'
        ];
    }
}
```